# React Native Android Build Fail Error on M1 Mac

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apple-m1

I cloned a project from github, and I get a build fail when I tried to run `react-native run-android`. I tried find the problem, but there are not many references, and most of the methods did not solve the problem. The error message is below:

```
Task :react-native-nodemediaclient:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
462 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 460 up-to-date
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-nodemediaclient:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-nodemediaclient:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find NodeMediaClient-Android-2.9.8.jar (com.github.NodeMedia:NodeMediaClient-Android:2.9.8).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/NodeMedia/NodeMediaClient-Android/2.9.8/NodeMediaClient-Android-2.9.8.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-nodemediaclient:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-nodemediaclient:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find NodeMediaClient-Android-2.9.8.jar (com.github.NodeMedia:NodeMediaClient-Android:2.9.8).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/NodeMedia/NodeMediaClient-Android/2.9.8/NodeMediaClient-Android-2.9.8.jar
```

I tried deleting node_modules, and re-installing.
I also tried cleaning gradle, but still not working :(

It is working on ios, but not android. Does anyone have clue what is the problem?

- Mac M1 Chip
- OS: Monterey 12.4
- Java: 14.0.2

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android emulator, try to remove it from Android Studio (Divice Manager), and create new one .